# How can i merge all forms?

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I want to post all form fields in one new form and then submit it.
I use this code:

```
function submitAllDocumentForms() {
            var arrDocForms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
            var formCollector = document.createElement("form");
            with(formCollector)
            {
                method = "post";
                action = "";
                name = "formCollector";
                id = "formCollector";
            }
            for(var ix=0;ix<arrDocForms.length;ix++) {
                appendFormVals2Form(arrDocForms[ix], formCollector);
            }
            document.body.appendChild(formCollector);
            formCollector.submit();

            }
        /* Function: add all elements from ``frmCollectFrom´´ and append them to ``frmCollector´´ before returning ``frmCollector´´*/
        function appendFormVals2Form(frmCollectFrom, frmCollector) {
            var frm = frmCollectFrom.elements;
            for(var ix = 0 ; ix < frm.length ; ix++)
                frmCollector.appendChild(frm[ix]);
            return frmCollector;
        }
```

But it submit every second field. How can i fix it?
My form look like this:

```
<form method="post">
<select class="..">
                                    <option value="">?</option>
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Best practice is to not use the `with` statement: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/

Comment: ok,i will change it. thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged jQuery in the question I figure the following should work.

```
$('<form />', {method:'POST'}).append($('form :input')).submit();
```

This creates a new `form` element and sets the `method` attribute to `POST`. It then appends the inputs from every other `form` element on the page. Finally it submits your newly created `form` element.